# Gorm: Find row where column value is present in given array

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

Let's say I have an entity Student. I want to create a generic filter that can take multiple parameters and based upon that can return the result. For example, I should be able to find students whose age is 10, whose class teacher is XYZ etc.

So far, this is the code that I have

Filter class looks like this

```golang
type MyCustomerFilter struct {
    Age int
    ClassTeacher string
    Names []string  // This is what I want to support
}
```

```golang
filters := make(map[string]interface{})
if myCustomFilter.Age > 0 {
    filters["student.age"] = myCustomFilter.Age
}

if len(myCustomFilter.Names) > 0 {
    filters["student.name IN ?"] = myCustomFilter.Names  // This is not working
}
```

The code that reads the database looks like this

```golang
db.Table("student").
    Joins(...).
    Where(filters).
    Select(...)
    ...
```

Here, the "age" filter is working properly as expected but I'm not able to formulate how to search the value in given array of values. The code I've written above is working. Additionally, I couldn't find any other example on the web.

```golang
if len(myCustomFilter.Names) > 0 {
    filters["student.name IN ?"] = myCustomFilter.Names  // This is not working
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought, I was overthinking.

I just had to assign the value irrespective of whether an array or a single value Gorm will automatically take care of converting the query in `WHERE value in (...)` when the target is an array and `WHERE VALUE = ...` when the value is a single.

I just modified my code as below and it worked.

```golang
if len(myCustomFilter.Names) > 0 {
    filters["student.name"] = myCustomFilter.Names  // This is not working
}
```